# sql server equivalent of Oracle High Water Mark

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know a way I can find how many records a table has previously held / how many pages it has had / some other way to identify its previous max size?  The result does not have to be totally accurate but rather indicate the scale.

We have a table that fulls and empties with a queue of jobs.  I need to be able to identify if it has previously grown large.

Comment: This is much better asked on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is more suitable for [dba.se]. Voting to close and migrate there. It's not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at using `sp_spaceused`, e.g.

```
EXEC sp_spaceused MyTableName
```

Output will give you current row count, space allocated, space reserved, data, index_size and unused.

If unused is high compared to reserved then you know it has grown large in the past.